# CoreData : Lost the managedObjectContext on my managedObject after a UITabbar switch

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have 2 view-controllers in a `UITabbar`.
My list of `managedObjects` works well in my first viewController (displayed in a CollectionView).

When I switch controllers (by changing `selectedViewController`), my `managedObjects` loose their context (and therefore their data).

I need to pass my entities to the other controller so how can I keep the context  ?

Thanks.

PS : this used to work with my previous Xcode (now 9.3 with Swift 3.3) !

Here the pseudo-code of my switch method :

```
//context is fine, and so are the properties
NSLog("Context: %@", myEntities[0].managedObjectContext)
NSLog("My label: %@", myEntities[0].label)

//switch tabbar
theTabbar.selectedItem = 1 

//managedObjectContext and label are now nil !
NSLog("Context: %@", myEntities[0].managedObjectContext)
NSLog("My label: %@", myEntities[0].label)
```

Comment: That can be because your object is not storing in Persistent storage. Pleas share your code

Comment: How you are passing it to another Controller?

Comment: Passed or not, the context is nil. I have added pseudo code.

Comment: Where you have defined NSManagedObjectContext property? It is in AppDelegate or in some where else in class?

Comment: The way you are accessing it is incorrect.

Comment: The NSManagedObjectContext property is in a singleton manager class.